# In a ajax request, is there a server way to get the js document.location?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, browser, client-server

**Context:**

Hi, the system that I'm working hás a definition of authorization like this:

> > For any node in Mvc.sitemap exists a permission associated.

Now I'm working in a custom Authorize Attribute that will check the authorization based on permissions in Mvc.sitemap.

Before anyone criticizes this approach, I must say that I can not change it, all permissions are already written in Mvc.sitemap.

It's simple to rescue the permission attribute, in each sitemap tag (xml tag) assossiated with each pages that are described in the sitemap file, but there are pages that are not described in the file. In sitemap file has definitions to view pages, but don't have definitions to partial view pages.

**The Question:**

In a ajax request, is there a server way to get the js `document.location`?

I mean, if I receive a request from ajax to a partial view, in browser the url (or in js: `document.location`) will be the url to the "main" view of my partial view. So I'll can search in sitemap to this url (the "main" url), and not the current url (the partial view url).

Answer (score 0):

Of course any data can be added to an ajax query.  The current page url is typically sent in the `referer` header, or you can write a wrapper that always includes it as a parameter.  On the other hand, you can't trust data that the client sends to the server and you certainly shouldn't make permission decisions based on it.

If you really need to make security decisions based on the page that the web service is invoked from, you can create a token in the page and include that in each ajax call.  Then you'll verify that the token is valid and that it grants the caller the required access before continuing with the request.